The problem with the boolean modifier
Task: to make a small bulge in the cube in the shape of a part. When using the modifier, the cube's surface does not behave as it should, and no distinct bulge is obtained. Normals seem to be fine. I made the details from curves and then converted them into a mesh.If necessary, I can attach a file, just tell me how to do it. 



You probably want the modifier to be set on Union if you want to add the shapes. Also, try setting the solver to Exact if you have issues with Fast. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

could you please share your file?
